# Highcharts highlight area between two lines

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following chart where I have two lines

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

```
series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
```

The thing I want to achieve is to highlight the space between Tokyo and London, is this possible with Highcharts?

(similar with http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/WRcj9/)

Can someone explain me how to achieve this or knows a better way to do this?

Comment: can you please elaborate it better way, can you please show your example here or how it display ?

Comment: so i  want that between tokio and london to be a color or something

Comment: i mean to say have you implemented it, can you please show me ? paste you full code @Hiero

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya its the first jsfiddle link, for the moment i have just 2 lines

Comment: You want like http://jsfiddle.net/fpdn8031/

Comment: no, the highlight part should be between the two lines, not between lines and x axis

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/WRcj9/light/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution I could think of for this is to create a new "arearange" series which is between the two series and hide it from the legend.

Something like :

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        },        
            {               
                type: "arearange",            
            data: [
            [3.9, 7.0],
            [4.2,6.9],
            [5.7,9.5],
            [8.5,14.5],
            [11.9, 18.2 ],
            [15.2, 21.5 ],
            [17.0, 25.5 ],
            [16.6, 26.5 ],
            [14.2, 23.3 ],
            [10.3, 18.3 ],
            [6.6, 13.9],
            [4.8, 9.6 ]
            ],
            showInLegend: false
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {            
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cs1zuzos/

Note: You'll need to use `highcharts-more.js` to do this.