# Highcharts highlight area between two lines with 2 different colors whether a serie is above or under the second serie

Tags: highcharts, highlight

We're trying to highlight area between two series but with a different color depending the green serie is :

- above (=positive)
- or under (=negative)

the blue serie.

This is basically what we want :

[image]

We found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688339/highcharts-highlight-area-between-two-lines#answer-36690986) and from this one we built this result which is ugly as the fillColor doesn't stop at the intersection:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 10, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9.6]
        },        
            {               
                type: "arearange",            
            data: [
            [3.9, 7.0],
            [4.2, 6.9],
            [5.7, 9.5],
            [8.5, 10],
            [11.9, 11]
            ],
            showInLegend: false,
            color: "red"
        }, 
        {               
                type: "arearange",            
            data: [
            [],
            [],
            [],
            [],
            [11.9, 11 ],
            [15.2, 10 ],
            [17.0, 10 ],
            [16.6, 10 ],
            [14.2, 10 ],
            [11.3, 10 ],
            [6.6, 10],
            [4.8, 9.6]
            ],
            showInLegend: false,            
            color: "green"
        },
        {               
                type: "arearange",            
            data: [
            [],
            [],
            [],
            [],
            [],
            [],            
            [],
            [],
            [],
            [11.3, 10 ],
            [6.6, 10],
            [4.8, 9.6]
            ],
            showInLegend: false,            
            color: "red"
        },
        {            
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 11.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7d140ujx/).

How can we do to achieve our need described in the above screenshot?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think this question might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46473151/2977638. The accepted answer to that question recommends using "zones" for the `arearange` series, calculated on the fly using linear interpolation. Does that solution suffice for your use case?

Comment: Thanks @RNanoware, that's what I want. I probably didn't use the right keywords before searching to stack overflow. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color area between two lines based on difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473151/color-area-between-two-lines-based-on-difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RNanoware wrote, this is a duplicate of an existing question.

You can use arearange with properly set zones which you can calculate with the appropriate function. In addition, you can also add lines with these points that you can style as you like and hide the arearange in the legend using the `showInLegend: false` property.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q4jyb9ch/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.showInLegend

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks your demo is exactly what I was looking for !!!

Comment: The demo is excellent, specifically in showing how to style the surrounding lines in a manner similar to the image in this question. Even with the question being a duplicate, I think the answer adds significant value. Thank you for putting it together!